# MySQL single row table for configuration settings

Tags: mysql

I have a table with configuration settings like so:

```
+-----------------------------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
+-----------------------------+
| value1  | value2  | value3  |
+-----------------------------+
```

As shown, there is one and only one row, so it does not have a primary key. The question is, how do SELECT or UPDATE the row? Particularly the UPDATE since there is no primary key

Comment: You can just run an Update statement without a WHERE condition and then it updates all rows. But it will be better just to add a Primary Key

Comment: Analize which combination of column give you great uniqueness..put them in where clause.But atleast have `primary key` or `composite primary key`

Answer (score 2):

Simply leave out the `WHERE` condition:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `Column1` = 'new value';
```

or for select:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`;
-- or
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 1;
```

To make sure there is always a row, insert an empty row after table creation:

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ();
```

Comment: Yes, but: "there is one and only one row"

Comment: Yes. There is one and only one row. I think this is the correct answer. But do I create an empty row at table creation? Because this would fail if there are 0 rows (no configuration yet)

Comment: This is true, but then the value is not saved :-) I added instructions to insert an empty row after table creation, that way this problem is solved aswell!

Comment: Also a sidenote: As Danyal mentioned in a comment: Is a single row table really the right solution to your problem? If it's configuration data you want to save, it's probably easier to write it to a file. You only have to read the config once (at the start of your program) and keep it in memory afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Combination of all of three, it is not a good practice though, you must have a primary key to ease up things and keep it auto-incremented.

In your case, if you want to update column 1.

```
update table1 set column1='newValue' 
where column1='value1' and column2='value2' and column3='value3'
```

Comment: This works but it is a) quite complicated and b) you have to read the row before you can write (because you need to know the three values)

Comment: How do I handle if there are 0 rows? (There is no configuation yet)
Should I make an empty row at table creation?

Comment: @userx01 this woud be the easiest way, yes. Otherwise you'd have to check if the row is already present every time you want to update a value.

Comment: yes, it is better to add a row.. and keep it the part of the script.. I think you want to save some sort of configuration, why don't you keep it in a config file? @userx01

Comment: like from an ini file? It is not a configuation per se, but values that are static to all users

Comment: if it is static, you don't you use ...static map data structure in your application? or keep the global values.. if they are dynamic add them in config..if you want to give some ease to the user..keep them in table so that users can modify via app